# How to stream raspivid to Linux and OSX using GStreamer, VLC or Netcat?

Tags: linux, camera, vlc, macos

How can I stream video stream to Linux or OS X using raspivid and either VLC, GStreamer or Netcat?

Comment: You can find some information about RTSP streaming  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/is-it-possible-to-stream-h-264-with-rtsp-on-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 37, accepted):

- Netcat (nc) seems to be the one with the smallest delay.
- In my experience, VLC has the biggest delay. On the other hand, there is a VLC client for Android, which is convenient.
- `<IP-OF-THE-CLIENT>` is the IP of the computer that should receive the video stream.
- `<IP-OF-THE-RPI>` is the IP of the Raspberry Pi.

## Using Netcat:

#### On the client

(Run the command on the client first, and then on the server (RPi)).

**Linux**

```
nc -l 2222 | mplayer -fps 200 -demuxer h264es -
```

**OS X**

```
nc -l 2222 | mplayer -fps 200 -demuxer h264es -
```

#### On the RPi

```
/opt/vc/bin/raspivid -t 0 -w 300 -h 300 -hf -fps 20 -o - | nc <IP-OF-THE-CLIENT> 2222
```

## Using GStreamer:

#### On the client

**Linux**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=<IP-OF-THE-RPI> port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

**OS X**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=<IP-OF-THE-RPI> port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! osxvideosink sync=false
```

#### On the RPi

```
/opt/vc/bin/raspivid -t 0 -hf -fps 20 -w 300 -h 300 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=<IP-OF-THE-RPI> port=5000
```

## Using VLC

#### On the client

The client might even be on a mobile phone (I tried on Android).

Simply open from the network in the VLC client:

```
http://<IP-OF-THE-RPI>:8090
```

#### On the RPi

```
/opt/vc/bin/raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 640 -h 360 -fps 25|cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8090}' :demux=h264
```

Comment: Pi version doesn't work. I mean it doesn't work how it should. Client ip?

Comment: I agree, netcat has the lowest latency. But why do you use 200fps?  My stream is 30fps, but setting mplayer to 60 looks best, I don't know why.  If I set mplayer to 30 then it adds 1-2 seconds latency

Comment: Why does netcat have the lowest latency ?

Answer (score 30):

better:

**on the rpi:**

raspivid -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -hf -ih -fps 20 -o - | nc -k -l 2222

**on your computer:**

mplayer -fps 200 -demuxer h264es ffmpeg://tcp://10.0.1.3:2222

supports reconnecting

Comment: On the raspberry pi, I had to use the `-p` parameter to set the port: `raspivid -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -hf -ih -fps 20 -o - | nc -k -l -p 2222`

Comment: Thanks for the `mplayer` command. It works also with the newer `raspivid` which can stream to TCP without using `netcat`, like that: `raspivid -fps 20 -w 1280 -h 720 -t 0 -l -o tcp://0.0.0.0:2222` - and the play command is the same. I'm still looking for the correct URL for VLC streaming. It was something like `h264+tcp://example.org:2222`

Comment: Command is tcp/h264://example.org:2222. I am wondering how to play this type of stream on Android. Mobile phones have such poor apps.

Comment: On macOS: `brew install mplayer`.