# PiCamera circular buffer piped to gstreamer

Tags: camera

I have a circular buffer that is monitored for motion and saves clips to disk.  Following the everything is a file philosophy, I should be able to write to a Unix pipe like I write to a file and make the gstreamer end work.  The problem is I can't figure out how to write my video to a pipe.

How do I write to a pipe?  Will writing to a pipe recreate the raspivid portion of this pipelint to create an RTSP stream that allows me to watch my dog at work?

```
raspivid -t 0 -w 1080 -h 720 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=VIDSERVERIP port=5000
```

[My code](https://gist.github.com/piyh/dd3721e560a4db5caa4bb00e88e794bb)

Comment: For capturing with raspivid and streaming, look at [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27082/how-to-stream-raspivid-to-linux-and-osx-using-gstreamer-vlc-or-netcat). But it is not clear if you want to keep the motion part to write to disk?

Comment: So in the example you linked, everyone is using raspivid and piping the output to gstreamer/netcat. My h264 video stream is handled through picamera. I know how to write my video frame by frame.  I don't know how to create a unix pipe from picamera that I can write my video to so I can replace the raspivid in the pipeline with my own code.

Comment: Do you need to create a unix pipe? Is it not possible to use pygst and/or gst to stream in python?

Comment: If you want to use unix pipes, you need to design your code to write the stream to standard output, perhaps in addition to storing it on disk..

Comment: I didn't know about pygst, it looks like it would allow me to do what I want. 

Another approach I was thinking of was creating an named pipe that I would open in python and write my video file to continuously.  Then I could do

cat named_pipe | gst-launch-1.0 .............

This would allow me to use the regular gst documentation/tutorials rather than pygst as it seems less people use gst.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending data down a pipe to another process in Python is quite simple, especially if your script spawns that other process. First, you to import want the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. Then you want to use the `Popen` class in there to spawn the other process, specifying `subprocess.PIPE` as the `stdin` value. As you might expect, that'll cause a pipe to be spawned for communication to the other process via its stdin file.

Then it's just a matter of using the process' stdin as the recording output. The one thing to bear in mind is that you need to close the stdin pipe once recording is finished; picamera won't do it for you because it didn't open the pipe (you did via Popen), so it won't presume to close it for you:

```py
import picamera
import subprocess

# start the gstreamer process with a pipe for stdin
gstreamer = subprocess.Popen([
    'gst-launch-1.0', '-v',
    'fdsrc',
    '!', 'h264parse',
    '!', 'rtph264pay', 'config-interval=1', 'pt=96',
    '!', 'gdppay',
    '!', 'tcpserversink', 'host=YOUR-PI-IP', 'port=5000'
    ], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# initialize the camera
camera = picamera.PiCamera(resolution=(1280, 720), framerate=25)
camera.hflip = True

# start recording to gstreamer's stdin
camera.start_recording(gstreamer.stdin, format='h264', bitrate=2000000)
camera.wait_recording(10)
camera.stop_recording()

# signal to gstreamer that the data's finished then wait for it to terminate
gstreamer.stdin.close()
gstreamer.wait()
```

As to the rest of your code - you've got some good stuff there, but some can be simplified with a few new toys introduced in picamera 1.11. Specifically, have a look at the new [PiCameraCircularIO.copy_to method](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/api_streams.html#picamera.PiCameraCircularIO.copy_to), and the clear method (just above it in the docs). Those can be used to greatly simplify (or even eliminate) your `write_video` function.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, straight from the picamera man himself!  Thanks a ton!