# How to rotate motion's output

Tags: python, raspicam, motion

I've made a pan/tilt device with a raspberry pi 3 and I'm looking for a way to flip the stream when the camera tilts past 90 degrees.  I'm using [mjpg-streamer](https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer) with motion, but wondering if streaming from python to motion is possible.  That way I can do things like `cam.vflip = true`.  Is this possible?  Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**  I have been testing with this code

```
from picamera import *
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

with PiCamera() as cam:
    stream = PiCameraCircularIO(cam, seconds=10)## I have tested with multiple types of streams, all the same reasult.
    cam.start_recording(stream, format='h264')
    cam.wait_recording(10)
    cam.stop_recording()

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'video/h264')
        self.end_headers()
        stream.copy_to(self.wfile)
        return

def start():
    server_address = ('192.168.1.200', 7878)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)
    print('server starting')
    httpd.serve_forever()
start()
```

The server works and the file comes across, but when I play it with vlc media player on my windows 10 pc it just looks black.

Comment: I don't know much about motion (I've no idea how it takes its input), but it's easy to have the camera [output an MJPEG stream to a pipe](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51299/picamera-circular-buffer-piped-to-gstreamer/51387#51387) for another process to read (or a socket, or whatever else you're using to connect mpg-streamer to motion).

Comment: @DaveJones Here are the [docs](http://lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuide) for motion.  I have no experience with subprocess so I don't know what that program does.  I have been feeding input to motion via the netcam setting in the config.